# C++ OpenMP on multiple nodes

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a question...

I know OpenMP on a single computer over the multiple cores in that machine, but is OpenMP capable of running over several nodes like 2 machines? Or do I absolutely have to use MPI? I know OpenMP has shared memory architecture, where MPI is distributed memory architecture, so is my assumption correct that OpenMP will only work on a single machine?

Comment: openmp will work only on single machine, because it is thread management framework, open mpi is distributed calculations framework - it will run on several computers

Comment: Is there any other parallelization tools I can use other than MPI for parallel code on multiple machines? How about GPU? If I set up a GPU in 2 machines will i be able to run code in parallel that way over both machines?

Comment: you can try map-reduce, not sure about GPU - as you need to send network messages between computers

Comment: GPU is **not a tool**. It is a piece of hardware, you can imagine it as a standalone shared memory machine you send the data to it it does the calculations and sends it back. GPUs have hundreds of cores but these cores are only capable of straightforward calculations (e.g. no or very slow if\else branching). Therefore if you use a GPU you may not need to use several machines as you will be using hundreds of cores already but the GPU may not be able to do what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

you must recode your app to a 2 level parallelism:

mpi - you reduce your task to a nodes. mpi works with a process.

openmp - parallel into node. openmp works with threads.